# Confirmation message in same page after submission

Tags: forms

I buy a Dreamweaver template and it comes with a Form page.But when I submit the message it sends me to another page with only text in it.
So I want to change it, so it can display a message after the submit buttom.

This is the CONTACT FORM inserted in a HTML page:

```
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="status alert alert-success contact-status"></div>
                <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                    <!-- Name Field Starts -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nombre: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="NOMBRE">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- Name Field Ends -->
                    <!-- Email Field Starts -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Correo Electrónico: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="EMAIL">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- Email Field Ends -->
                    <!-- Phone No Field Starts -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phoneno" class="sr-only">Teléfono: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" required placeholder="TELÉFONO (10 DÍGITOS)">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- Phone No Field Ends -->

                    <!-- Message Field Starts -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message" class="sr-only">Mensaje: </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="message" id="message" required placeholder="MENSAJE"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- Message Field Ends -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-secondary text-uppercase" value="Enviar Mensaje">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <!-- Contact Form Ends -->
```

And this is the sendemail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$phoneno = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phoneno']));
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'myemail@domain.com';
$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Phone NO: ' . $phoneno . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;
$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
echo json_encode($status);
die; 
?>
```

Hopping you can help me

Comment: A workaround could be, in sendemail.php, after die, redirect to the contact page with querystrign message and read queryString to display message . For querystring reading you can use javascript.

Comment: Could you put an example what I have to add in my code?